# is it possible to bind two observer at once?

Tags: ios, rx-swift

Like:

```
btn.rx.tap
   .bind(to: ViewA.rx.isHidden && ViewB.rx.isHidden)
   .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

so once i tap the btn,ViewA and ViewB both hidden at once!
is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[isHidden](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxCocoa/iOS/UIView%2BRx.swift#L16) requires `Bool`, so first, you need to convert your [tap](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxCocoa/iOS/UIButton%2BRx.swift#L17) to `Bool`. Answering your question - here is what you can do:

```swift
btn.rx.tap
    .map { _ in true }
    .bind(onNext: { value in
        ViewA.isHidden = value
        ViewB.isHidden = value
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

or

```swift
let hiddenStatus = BehaviorRelay(value: false)

btn.rx.tap
    .map { _ in true }
    .bind(to: hiddenStatus)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

hiddenStatus.bind(to: ViewA.rx.isHidden).disposed(by: disposeBag)
hiddenStatus.bind(to: ViewB.rx.isHidden).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no real need for an intermediate `BehaviorRelay` as in SaikOs answer. Simply bind twice:

```swift
btn.rx.tap
   .bind(to: ViewA.rx.isHidden)
   .disposed(by: disposeBag)

btn.rx.tap
   .bind(to: ViewB.rx.isHidden)
   .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 2):

With RxSwift 5 you can do it almost the way you thought it should be:

```
button.rx.tap
    .map { true }
    .bind(to: viewA.rx.isHidden, viewB.rx.isHidden)
    .disposed(by: bag)
```